# Positioning recaptcha puzzle challenge when using Invisible recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Is there a way to integrate the puzzle challenge (when captcha thinks you are a robot) in a specific area of a website (in a target div) when using an ***invisible*** recaptcha ?

All I tried did fail :

- using `data-badge="inline"` only impacts the recaptcha badge (logo)
- using `data-size="normal"` (instead of `data-size="invisible"` give the ability to position it .. but well it's no more an invisible repactcha

=> everytime the puzzle challenge is appended before the `</body>`tag. I would like to integrate the challenge better in my site... is that possible ?

Not working fiddle (to open in a private nav tab) :
https://jsfiddle.net/n3wy6czv/1/